# Why do I get this "fields not in fieldnames" error when writing Python dict to csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'R', '0', '0', '3'
```

when I run this example piece of code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[   0,    0,    2,    5,    0],
          [1478, 3877, 3674, 2328, 2539],
          [1613, 4088, 3991, 6461, 2691],
          [1560, 3392, 3826, 4787, 2613],
          [1608, 4802, 3932, 4477, 2705],
          [1576, 3933, 3909, 4979, 2685],
          [  95,  229,  255,  496,  201],
          [   2,    0,    1,   27,    0],
          [1438, 3785, 3589, 4174, 2215],
          [1342, 4043, 4009, 4665, 3033]],
    index=['05-01-11', '05-02-11', '05-03-11', '05-04-11', '05-05-11',
           '05-06-11', '05-07-11', '05-08-11', '05-09-11', '05-10-11'],
    columns=['R003', 'R004', 'R005', 'R006', 'R007']
)

myDATA=df.to_dict();
header=myDATA.keys()

with open("TestTry.csv", "w") as g:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(g, delimiter=",", fieldnames=header,lineterminator='\r\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in myDATA:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I could not figure out how to overcome this error! Your help would be appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any good reason you are not using [df.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)?

Comment: oops! I am a newbie in Python and forgot that :). Still, as I am in the process of learning Python, it may be helpful to understand what was causing the error, if you can kindly explain it?

Comment: your `writer` is `DictWriter`, whose `writerow` method accept `dictionary`.

Comment: @Tiny.D I would accept your answer if you do post it. Please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DeepSpace suggested, you can use pandas `df.to_csv` to save `dataframe` to `csv` file.

Your code problem is that you have to convert dataframe to a list, which contain dictionary element like: `list like [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]`, then you can for loop the list to write the dict element with `DictWriter` into `csv` file, meanwhile, you can add the `indexes` as well, like this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[   0,    0,    2,    5,    0],
          [1478, 3877, 3674, 2328, 2539],
          [1613, 4088, 3991, 6461, 2691],
          [1560, 3392, 3826, 4787, 2613],
          [1608, 4802, 3932, 4477, 2705],
          [1576, 3933, 3909, 4979, 2685],
          [  95,  229,  255,  496,  201],
          [   2,    0,    1,   27,    0],
          [1438, 3785, 3589, 4174, 2215],
          [1342, 4043, 4009, 4665, 3033]],
    index=['05-01-11', '05-02-11', '05-03-11', '05-04-11', '05-05-11',
           '05-06-11', '05-07-11', '05-08-11', '05-09-11', '05-10-11'],
    columns=['R003', 'R004', 'R005', 'R006', 'R007']
)

myDATA=df.to_dict(orient='records') #Convert DataFrame to dictionary(records) : list like [{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}] 
header = list(df.columns.values) #get column name ['R003', 'R004', 'R005', 'R006', 'R007']
index = list(df.index) #get index name ['05-01-11', '05-02-11', '05-03-11', '05-04-11', '05-05-11', '05-06-11', '05-07-11', '05-08-11', '05-09-11', '05-10-11']

with open("TestTry.csv", "w") as g:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(g, delimiter=",", fieldnames=['index']+header,lineterminator='\r\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    for i,row in enumerate(myDATA):
        temp_row = row
        temp_row['index'] = index[i] #add index into dict
        writer.writerow(temp_row)
```